# jQuery: autocomplete multiple ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete

the last 5 days I fall into despair. I am forced to use an ajax interface for getting usernames in an autocomplete input. This works fine but I also want to add some user-avatars. Adding an avatar-image to autocomplete search results works fine too but only by typing avatar-path directly without ajax response to _renderItem() like

```
//see complete code below
var inner_html = '<img src="img/avatar-123.png" /><span>' + item.label + '</span>';
```

I want to manipulate the first ajax JSON-result:

```
            {"data":[{"label": "Simon",
                    "value":{   "shareType":0,
                                "shareWith":"Simon"
                            }
                }],
         "status":"success"}
```

in something like this:

```
{"data":[{  "label": "Simon",
                    "value":{   "shareType":0,
                                "shareWith":"Simon"
                                "avatar":"img/avatar-123.png"
                            }
                }],
         "status":"success"}
```

But adding a new avatar-Object to the json-Object don't work :( Do you have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
    $("#search").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    focus : function(event, focused) {
        event.defaultPrevented();
    },
    source: function(search, response) {
        $.when(
            //get usernames
            $.get(OC.filePath('core', 'ajax', 'share.php'), {
                fetch : 'getShareWith',
                search : search.term
            })
        /*example result: 
        {"data":[{  "label": "Simon",
                    "value":{   "shareType":0,
                                "shareWith":"Simon"
                            }
                }],
         "status":"success"}*/

         //result of first ajax goes in the next round
        ).then(function(content) {

            $.each(content.data, function(i, item) {
                //get avatars for usernames
                $.get(OC.filePath('ownchat', 'ajax', 'get_avatar.php'), {
                    username: content.data[i].label
                }, function(img) {
                //firebug says everthing is working till here 

                    //now I want to add a new avatar-Object to the json-Object
                    content.data[i].value.avatar = img;
                });
            });

            //the following code-result is empty
                //alert(content.data[0].value.avatar);
            //but calling
                //setTimeout(function(){
                //      response(content.data);
                //  },2000);
            //in place of the following line, it works sometimes 

            response(content.data);

        });
    }/*,
    manipulate search result 
    response: function (e, ui) {

        This do not work too :(

        for(i in ui.content) {
            $.get(OC.filePath('ownchat', 'ajax', 'get_avatar.php'), {
                user_id: ui.content[i].label
            }, function(img) {
                ui.content[i].avatar.push = { avatar: img };
            });
        }
    }*/
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    var inner_html = '<img src="'+ item.value.avatar +'" /><span>' + item.label + '</span>';

    return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append(inner_html)
            .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Sorry for the long text but I hope you can help.

Greetings André

Answer (score 1):

Once i also needed this type of requirement in which username and picture was needed to show, after trying alot, what i came up was build my own custom autocomplete, and it works great i reuse it whenever it is required, you can see it here:

http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/12/facebook-and-linkedin-like-searching.html

Comment: Thanks! I will compare yours with mine ;) (In the last hour I wrote my own custom autocomplete and it works fine but it's a bit tricky because of the two ajax responses...)
Maybe someone knows a way with autocomplete() even so?